# How to delete a line which contains a specific syntax but I want to avoid a line which contains another word

Tags: linux, gvim

How can I remove a line with a specific word but keeping in mind: if another word is found, then don't delete the line.
For example, I'm deleting a line having `sup` or `gnd` with `:%s/.*sup.*//g` or `:%s/.*gnd.*//g`, but it is also deleting some lines which is breaking breaking loop line as well.

I don't want to delete lines which have `module` in the same line as `gnd` or `sup`.
Any idea how to conquer the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
:v/module/s/\v.*(sup|gnd).*//
```

- `:v/pattern/cmd` runs `cmd` on the lines that do *not* match the pattern
- `\v` turns on *very-magic* so that all the `(`, `|` characters are treated as regexp operator without the need to prefix them with `\`.

Note that it *empties* but otherwise doesn't *remove* the lines that contain `sup` or `gnd`. To remove them, since you can't nest `g`/`v` commands, you could use `vim`'s negative look ahead regexp operator in one `g` command instead:

```
:g/\v^(.*module)@!.*(sup|gnd)/d
```

- `:g/pattern/cmd` runs `cmd` on the lines the *do* match the pattern
- `(pattern)@!` (with *very-magic*) matches with zero width if the *pattern* is not matched at that position, so `^(.*module)@!` matches at the beginning of  a line that doesn't contain `module`.

There's also the option of piping to `sed` or `awk`:

```
:%!sed -e /module/b -e /sup/d -e /gnd/d
```

- `/module/b` branches off (and the line is printed) for lines that contain `module`.
- for the lines that don't, we carry on with the next two commands that delete the line if it contains `sup` or `gnd` respectively.

or:

```
:%!awk '/sup|gnd/ && ! /module/'
```

If you wanted to *find* those files that need those lines removed and remove them, you'd probably want to skip `vim` and do the whole thing with text processing utilities. On a GNU system:

```
find . ! -name '*.back' -type f -size +3c -exec gawk '
  /sup|gnd/ && ! /module/ {printf "%s\0", FILENAME; nextfile}' '{}' + |
  xargs -r0 sed -i.back -e /module/b -e /sup/d -e /gnd/d
```

(here saving a backup of the original files as `the-file.back`, change `-i.back` to `-i` if you don't need the backup).

- `find` finds the regular files whose name doesn't end in `.back` and whose size is at  least 4 bytes (smaller ones can't possibly contain a line that contains `sup` or `gnd` (and the line delimiter)) and runs `gawk` with the paths of the corresponding files as arguments.
- when `gawk` finds a line in any of those files that match, it prints the path of the file (`FILENAME` special variable) delimited with a NUL character (for `xargs -0`) and skips to the next file.
- `xargs -r0` processes that `gawk` outputs to run `sed` with those file paths as arguments.
- `sed` edits the file in place.

Comment: I've tried in the linux with 
grep -r "sup" <file_name> | grep -vE "^module" | <list of line That i need>
I've list of line but I can't use/find suitable command after 2nd pipe

How to process after pipe, because after second I've list line which has sup but exclude module line, but I am not able to delete to those line from the file...

Comment: @CLEX420, see edit.

Comment: Why it is saying "find: missing argument to `-exec'" while using find command solution you gave

Comment: @CLEX420, sorry my bad, I forgot the {} +. See edit (I still haven't tested it).

Comment: It says:
------------
find . ! -name '*.back' -type f -size +3c -exec gawk '/sup/ && ! /module/ {printf "%s\0", cfg_pmc_por_top.v; nextfile}' '{}' + | xargs -r0 sed -i.bak -e /module/b -e /sup/d
-------------------
gawk: /sup/ && ! /module/ {printf "%s\0", cfg_pmc_por_top.v; nextfile}
gawk:                                                    ^ syntax error

Comment: Your very first command did the job, but I want to lean how did you make this syntax or when can i learn these switches?

Comment: @CLEX420, it has to be literal `FILENAME`, which gawk replaces with the name of the current file.

Comment: See `info gawk`, `info find`, `info xargs`, `info sed` for details. For `vim`, see the `:help` command (`:h :g`, `:h :v`, `:h pattern.txt`)

Comment: Is is not possible to pipe few more words with module
:v/module/s/\v.*(sup|gnd).*// for here, like if I want to add input or output & remove all lines except module/input/output?

Comment: You can do `:v/module\|input\|output/s/...//` or again use `\v` to avoid having to enter those backslashes: `:v/\vmodule|(in|out)put/s/...//`. See `:h pattern.txt` for details on vim's regexp syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Found it as 
:v/(module\|input\|output)/s/\v.*.*/